# Pandas Pivot table: How to sort top n nows in the pivot table by category and generate new dataframe?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['AUD','CAD', 'IND','JPY', 'AUD', 'CHY', 'IND', 'KRL', 'SRI', 'KRW', 'CAD'], 
   'area': ['N','S','N','E','W','S','NE','N','S','SE','N'], 'gdp': [349,65,60,88,75,100,200,250,150,210,160], 'income': [7000,2300,5000,1000,550,1000,2060,2750,1450,2610,1650], 'expense': [500,300,700,600,500,900,206,275,1405,210,150]})

df = df.pivot_table(index=['country','area'],values=['gdp'],aggfunc='sum').sort_values(by = ['gdp'], ascending = False, axis = 0).head(5)
```

By applying above method, I am unable to see top 5 'country' based on 'gdp'. My expected output should be like below in dataframe. Please suggest. However, I tried to populate the expected output through MS excel to get a feel.

```
new_df = country    gdp expense income
             AUD    424 1000    7550
               N    349 500     7000
               W    75  500     550
             IND    260 906      7060
               N    60  700      5000
              NE    200 206     2060
             KRL    250 275      2750
               N    250 275     2750
             CAD    225 450     3950
               N    160 150     1650
               S    65  300      2300
              KRW   210 210     2610
               SE   210 210     2610

new_df = country    gdp expense income  area
             AUD    424 1000    7550      N, W
             IND    260 906     7060      N, NE
             KRL    250 275     2750      N
             CAD    225 450     3950      N,S
             KRW    210 210     2610      SE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
df.groupby('country', as_index=False).agg({'gdp': 'sum', 'area': ','.join}).sort_values(by='gdp', ascending=False).head(5)
```

**Output**

```
    country gdp area
0   AUD 349 N,W
5   KRL 250 N
6   KRW 210 SE
3   IND 200 N,NE
1   CAD 160 S,N
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Highly appreciate it. I just edited the the dataframe., so just to confirm if aggregate work with multiple columns ?

Comment: I have bigger dataframe and 'area' column is repeating with same values. Cant it be possible to show unique values in 'area' column ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use pivot for this, it can be done this way

```
df.groupby('country').agg({'gdp':'sum',
                          'area':','.join}).sort_values('gdp',ascending = False).head(5)
```

Output:

```
country  gdp  area          
AUD      424   N,W
IND      260  N,NE
KRL      250     N
CAD      225   S,N
KRW      210    SE
```

Comment: answer looks familiar :(

Comment: its the shortest way to do it, don't worry I didn't have to look at yours for this :)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Highly appreciate it. I edited the the dataframe., so just to confirm if aggregate work with multiple columns ?

Comment: I have bigger dataframe and 'area' column is repeating with same values. Cant it be possible to show unique values in 'area' column ?

Comment: yes it does, just keep adding the columns and the agg function pairs in the dictionary similar to gdp.

Comment: you can use 
`','.join(set(x))` as the agg function for getting the unique values